# typing next to iframe

Tags: video, text

How can I type next to my YouTube video? What do I need to add in my html code to have 3 testimonials (with pictures) nice and clear under each other?

Thanks in advance!

Kr,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dO89IXP0_v8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
```